# How to handle Extravehicular Activities?

Tags: savage-worlds, science-fiction

I'm preparing to run a Savage Worlds game using the Science Fiction Companion book.  There are a couple of references to 'going EV' on page 41 with regards to performing Hull Repairs.

Searching through the book I'm unable to find any rules about how to manage PCs when they decide to don a spacesuit and leave the ship for the cold vacuum of space.  It's possible I just missed it, if so please provide me a page reference.

If not — what sorts of skill checks or mechanics would be best suited to handle this sort of situation to keep the tension high, but not send my PCs hurtling into the darkness (without a chance for them to save themselves)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching the PDF, if you missed something, it is well-hidden. The Gravity rules on p27 cover tumbling and getting confused. Having the Zero-G Sickness Hindrance on p11 means you shouldn't try this. The Spacesuits on p17 protect you completely against vacuum and cold. Real spacewalking is actually fairly dull provided you're prepared.

Given all that, they get to make their Repair rolls to fix the ship. The problems start if they aren't properly prepared. Not having proper zero-G tools imposes significant penalties, probably -2. Not tethering yourself, and not having thrusters on your suit is a *really* bad idea. Having someone going EV with you who actually wants to cause you to have an accident ... needs a true hero.

Comment: So basically there's no unified guide, you gotta use your imagination and apply the scattered rules of the book as you see fit?

Comment: As far as I can see, yes.

Comment: A pity, really.

Comment: That does seem to be the case.  In the long run, I think I like that solution given the content available - although the references in the book seem to hint that perhaps they were considering more extensive EVA rules at one time or another.  I ran an EVA encounter after asking this question.  Once I knew I wasn't missing out on some proscribed set of rules this was perfectly satisfactory and the scene played out beautifully using trait rolls as you would in any other scene.